# Дерево каталогов на Php

Tags: php, jquery

Как можно сделать с помощью `Js`, чтобы после клика на папку или название папки, открывалось дерево подпапок, которые находятся внутри данной папки (на настоящее время, для того чтобы открыть подпапки нужно нажать на крестик).

[image: Foto]

Адрес кода php: [**Дерево каталогов на PHP**](http://htmlhook.ru/derevo-katalogov-na-php-jquery-css3.html)

Php код:

```
$path = ".";

function createDir($path = '.')
{   
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) 
    {
        echo '<ol class="tree">';

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
        {
            if (is_dir($path.$file) && $file != '.' && $file !='..')
                printSubDir($file, $path, $queue);
            else if ($file != '.' && $file !='..')
                $queue[] = $file;
        }

        printQueue($queue, $path);
        echo "</ol>";
    }
}

function printQueue($queue, $path)
{
    foreach ($queue as $file) 
    {
        printFile($file, $path);
    } 
}

function printFile($file, $path)
{
    echo "<li class=\"file\"><a href=\"".$path.$file."\">$file</a></li>";
}

function printSubDir($dir, $path)
{
    echo "<li class=\"toggle\">$dir<input type=\"checkbox\">";
    createDir($path.$dir."/");
    echo "</li>";
}

createDir($path);
```

Пробовал так (Js):

```
$('.toggle3').click(function () {

    if ($(".check").is(':checked')) {
        $(".check").removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $(".check").attr("checked", "checked");
    }

});
```

но открываются одновременно все папки, а тот код что есть на сайте скрипта у меня почему-то очень каряво работает.

Comment: А что значит каряво работает? а там есть ссылка на демо проект........http://htmlhook.ru/downloads/tree.zip.. в котором дерево работает вообще без javascript, чисто на `css`

Comment: там не все папки и подпапки открываются

Comment: Все открываются. просто **1)** в `$path` надо написать так `$path = __DIR__."/";` **2)** в `foreach` проверять что есть `if ($queue) {
   foreach ($queue as $file) {
    printFile($file, $path);
   } 
  }`  все работает